# pgAdmin showing type[] but not type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I've created an `ENUM` type in PostgreSQL `tribool` I've created table column with `tribool` type and now I an writing a function that takes an argument of type `tribool`. However, pgAdmin only shows `tribool[]` in the drop down, but not `tribool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously a minor bug in the current version of pgAdmin 1.14.2. I created a ticket in the project bugtracker:
http://code.pgadmin.org/trac/ticket/360

Thank you for reporting it.

Guillaume Lelarge applied a fix. Will be deployed with the next version 1.14.3.
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgadmin-hackers/2012-04/msg00032.php

---

pgAdmin v1.14.3 is out and the bug is fixed.